# How Insert and Populate DateTime when Using Calendar.getInstance() on Android Studio

Tags: android, mysql, date, datetime, datepicker

i am a newbie on Android Programming.
I have some problem with my app,

When i try to insert some date to the database using `Calendar.getInstance()`, the date column on database i set the type to `long` and the date successfully added. But in a strange value.

When i wan to show the date on my `Listview`, i try to select the date from database, the date is showing strange value, isn't a date format like 11-09-2015 or etc but just "2046" or "2036".

I have completely confuse about this, i have searching on StackOverflow, there are some example but it using `DatePicker`, in here i think i am not using `DatePicker`.

I don't know what exactly i need to do. 
Please master help me,
Thanks Before.

NB. This is my code for `NewTransaction.java` (the activity which i use to pick the date) :

```
public class NewTransaction extends ActionBarActivity {
Button btnIDate;
Button btnIAdd;
Button btnICancel;
RadioButton RdIncome;
RadioButton RdOutcome;
EditText txtAmount, txtCashflow, txtType;
DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase db;
MainActivity mainAct = new MainActivity();
int year_x, month_x, day_x;
static final int DIALOG_ID=0;
public static long dateSelected;
public static Integer intAmount = null;
public static String month;
private boolean isUpdateTrans;
private String id, transname, transamount, transtype, transdate, transcategid;

//new trans ad tf salah fi input tgl
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_transaction);
    txtAmount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtAmount);
    txtCashflow = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtCashflow);
    txtType = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtType);
    RdIncome = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RdBtnIncome);
    RdOutcome = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RdBtnOutcome);

    String catSelected = mainAct.getCatSelected();

    onButtonClickButtonListener(catSelected);
    selectDate();
    showDialogOnClick();
    //kena null object dsni entah knapa
    Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle!= null) {
        isUpdateTrans = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("update");
        if (isUpdateTrans) {
            System.out.print("isUpdate di NewTrans");
            id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("TransId");
            transname = getIntent().getExtras().getString("TransName");
            transamount = getIntent().getExtras().getString("TransAmount");
            transtype = getIntent().getExtras().getString("TransType");
            transdate = getIntent().getExtras().getString("CategDate");
            transcategid = getIntent().getExtras().getString("CategCategId");
            txtCashflow.setText(transname);
            txtType.setText(transtype);
            txtAmount.setText(transamount);
            btnIDate.setText(transdate);

        }
    }
}

private void selectDate(){
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    year_x = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month_x = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day_x = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    switchMonth(month_x);
    btnIDate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDate);
    btnIDate.setText("Date : " + day_x + "-" + month + "-" + year_x);
    //dateSelected = (year_x+month_x+day_x);
}

public void showDialogOnClick(){
    btnIDate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDate);
    btnIDate.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showDialog(DIALOG_ID);
                }
            }
    );

}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
    if (id == DIALOG_ID)
            return  new DatePickerDialog(this, dpickerListener , year_x, month_x, day_x);
    return null;

}

private String switchMonth(Integer month_x){
    switch(month_x){
        case 1 : month = "Jan";
            break;
        case 2 : month = "Feb";
            break;
        case 3 : month = "Mar";
            break;
        case 4 : month = "Apr";
            break;
        case 5 : month = "Mei";
            break;
        case 6 : month = "Jun";
            break;
        case 7 : month = "Jul";
            break;
        case 8 : month = "Aug";
            break;
        case 9 : month = "Sep";
            break;
        case 10 : month = "Okt";
            break;
        case 11 : month = "Nov";
            break;
        case 12 : month = "Des";
            break;
    }
    return month;
}

public DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpickerListener
        = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        year_x= year;
        month_x = monthOfYear + 1;
        day_x = dayOfMonth;
        switchMonth(month_x);
        btnIDate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDate);
        btnIDate.setText("Date : " + day_x + "-" + month + "-" + year_x);
        //Toast.makeText(NewTransaction.this, year_x + "/" + month_x + "/" + day_x, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dateSelected = view.getCalendarView().getDate();
        Toast.makeText(NewTransaction.this, "Date " + dateSelected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(myDatePicker.getCalendarView().getDate());
    }
};

private void clearText(){
    txtCashflow.clearComposingText();
    txtAmount.clearComposingText();
    txtType.clearComposingText();

}

public void onButtonClickButtonListener(final String catSelected){
        btnIAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddTrans);
        btnIAdd.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(RdIncome.isChecked()){
                            txtType.setText("Income");
                        }else{
                            txtType.setText("Outcome");
                        }
                        if (isUpdateTrans) {
                            //update
                            Toast.makeText(NewTransaction.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            intAmount = Integer.parseInt(txtAmount.getText().toString());
                            boolean isInserted = dbHelper.updateTransData(id, txtCashflow.getText().toString(),
                                    intAmount, txtType.getText().toString(), dateSelected, catSelected, null);
                            if (isInserted == true) {
                                Toast.makeText(NewTransaction.this, "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                clearText();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        NewTransaction.this,
                                        ViewCashflow.class
                                );
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else
                                Toast.makeText(NewTransaction.this, "Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            //insert
                            Toast.makeText(NewTransaction.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            intAmount = Integer.parseInt(txtAmount.getText().toString());
                            boolean isInserted = dbHelper.insertTransData(txtCashflow.getText().toString(),
                                    intAmount, txtType.getText().toString(), dateSelected, catSelected, null);
                            if (isInserted == true) {
                                Toast.makeText(NewTransaction.this, "Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                clearText();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        NewTransaction.this,
                                        ViewCashflow.class
                                );
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else
                                Toast.makeText(NewTransaction.this, "Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

        btnICancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCancelTrans);
        btnICancel.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                NewTransaction.this,
                                MainActivity.class
                        );
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_new_transaction_, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to get current date. It will format the date in `dd-MM-yyyy` format.

```
private static void selectDate() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String date = df.format(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println(date);

}
```

### EDIT

To use a `DatePickerDialog`

```
        DatePickerDialog dp = new DatePickerDialog(mContext, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Log.e("date", year + ":" + monthOfYear + ":" + dayOfMonth);
            }
        }, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        dp.show();
```

Comment: But how can the user pick the date by itself?? Like using calendar to get the date sir??

Comment: Use `DatePickerDialog`.

Comment: sir, is that right i save that Date on the Database witch String data type??

Comment: No, The best practice is to store them in date format (Database date format) itself..And no need to call me sir  :). Also if you want to ask another question first search Google and SO and if no results found ask here. (If the above answer helped you in current question, accept it so others can find it useful)

Comment: but base on few articles that i read on google, they said that there's no DateTime type data on SQLite,
so its make me a little bit confuse what type data i must use for.
hehhehe okay brother...

Comment: Okay. I thought your database was in your sever. In SQLlite there is no date type. You can use **TEXT** format.